# Can I omit the then part in an if statement?

Tags: bash

How would be the correct bash syntax for something like this:

```
if [ "$actual" == "$expected" ]; then 
  doNothing
else 
  echo "Error: actual: $actual. Expected: $expected"
fi
```

I am looking for something that works for all possible values of the variables "actual" and "expected". The content of the variables must not be interpreted/evaluated/expanded in any way. The script does not need to be portable (a bash only solution is ok).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the simplest do-nothing statement available:

```
if [ "$actual" = "$expected" ]; then 
  :
else 
  echo "Error: actual: $actual. Expected: $expected"
fi
```

(Note: One `=` not two in `[`/`test`.)

But a better idea is to just invert the test and remove the need for that entirely:

```
if [ "$actual" != "$expected" ]; then
  echo "Error: actual: $actual. Expected: $expected"
fi
```

Comment: I just read an accepted answer here (I cannot find it again) that suggests to use == instead of = . What is the difference? For simple cases both seem to work. What would be the negation of == ? Is it !== ?.

Comment: The POSIX `[`/`test` uses `=` for equality and `!=` for inequality ([ref](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_05)). bash (and likely many other shells) accept `==` in that usage as well but it isn't strictly spec. The bash-specific `[[` built-in test syntax ([ref](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b)) uses `==`/`!=` (but also accepts `=` for sanity's sake).

Comment: There seems to be no consensus if [ or [[ should be used.

Comment: They are different. `[` is portable. `[[` is a bash-ism. `[[` has some nice safety properties that `[` does not (but also at least one down-side, see my comment on DevSolar's answer). `[[` supports some tests that `[` doesn't as well.

Comment: What do you mean with "isn't strictly spec"? I thought the different shells are not compatible anyway?

Comment: There is a spec, I linked to a section of it before, for how POSIX shells should function. A common-base if you will. Not all shells adhere to that, not all do so as completely as others, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
if [ "$actual" != "$expected" ]; then 
  echo "Error: actual: $actual. Expected: $expected"
fi
```

Comment: `-ne` is a numeric comparison `!=` is string comparison. They are not equivalent.

Comment: What is the exact difference? A variable can contain a numerical value, too, can't it? Is there a difference between a variable containing the number 1 or the text 1?

Comment: The difference is when the value is **not** a number. `[ 5 = 5 ]` and `[ 5 -ne 3 ]` will both be true but `[ 5 -ne foo ]` will be a runtime error whereas `[ 5 != foo ]` will be false.

Comment: What should I use if I don't know in advance of the variables contain a string or numerical value or something else?

Comment: @etan: 07 and 7 are the same number and different strings. Just as one example.

Comment: @rici Very true. I obviously wasn't thinking clearly when I wrote that.

Comment: Which to use if you don't know what you are going to need to compare depends entirely on where your data is going to come from and what you need to correctly compare. Neither set of comparison operators will Just Work for all input sanely (without error checking/validation/etc.) around it.

Answer (score -1):

```
if [[ $actual != $expected ]]
then
    echo "Error: actual: $actual. Expected: $expected"
fi
```

Using the builtin `[[` has several advantages over `test` / `[`. For one, you don't get bitten if you don't quote variables containing whitespace.

`[[ ]]` also offers `<` and `>` for locale-aware lexicographic sorting, regular expression matching, and `=~`. Check [man bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions).

(Note Etan's comment though on at least one dissenting opinion. I haven't yet made up my mind whether this is a disadvantage or a feature to be exploited, but it is sure surprising.)

There's also the thing with putting `then` on a separate line, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: Why not expand on the advantages of `[[` over `[`?

Comment: `[[` also has (at least) one down-side with numeric comparisons. It recursively expands non-numeric values (see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29980940/258523) for a little about that).

Comment: @arco444: I added the difference that counts in the scope of the question.

Comment: @Etan: Good catch and caveat.

Comment: What are those advantages? What is the thing with then on a separate line? What is the exact difference of [[ and [ ?

Comment: @Gustave: A semicolon in bash seperates multiple commands in one line. I prefer not to do that, for aesthetic and practical reasons (like, line numbers referring to a single command, unambiguously). If you follow through on that style, `then` has to go on a separate line. It's like ANSI vs. Egyptian brackets, preference really.

Comment: @DevSolar: What do you mean with "get bitten if you don't quote variables containing whitespace"?

Comment: I don't understand this fully, but I guess that there are sitiuations where the values that the variables contain are interpreted/evaluated/expanded before the actual comparison is done. What should I do if I want to ensure that the values are taken as they are under all circumstances?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83336/discussion-between-devsolar-and-gustave).