# Do we still need to use `[...]` in Bash?

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

If I don't care about compatibility or portable issues, would I still need to use test construction `[...]` in Bash?

Many tutorials/books tell that `[[...]]` is better and more flexible than `[...]` e.g. `[[...]]` is support glob/regex, but today I still see many people prefer to use `[...]` as standard form.

What is a reason behind this? What `[...]` can do but `[[...]]` can not do?

Comment: `[...]` can cause errors that `[[ ... ]]` won't if you don't use proper whitespace and quote parameter expansions correctly. Otherwise, it is used solely to keep the shell script portable.

Comment: `[` is (more like) an ordinary command, with the same interpretation of parameters as any other command.  The `[[` command interprets arguments differently from other commands.  If you don't mind winding your brain around different ways that arguments are handled, use `[[`.  You'll be in good company — witness the earlier comment.  But `[` uses the same notations as any other command so it is a whole heap easier to use than `[[`.

Comment: When I start to learn Bash, several forms of test construction quite bother me, I always use Bash as a glue code for my project and I just need a best solution which don't care about portability/compatible issue. BTW, any important note about `[..]` please answer me below.

Comment: Most of the errors I see people make with `[` lead me to think they are applying a 3rd set of rules to it that don't apply to either `[[` or an ordinary command. If anything, I'd recommend only using the name `test` for that command if you are going to use it.

Comment: The generally received wisdom is "use `[[`" when portability isn't an issue.  Portability is an issue for me, and I've been shell programming for a long time — I prefer `[` because it is simpler for me to use because it is 'just a regular command with no special cases' (which is also not quite true, but the special cases have not caused me problems because I internalized the issues 30 years ago).  Your choice, but if you're really sure that portability isn't an issue, then probably go with `[[`.

Comment: Could I ask you something? Normally, when people keep using `[` or use some old syntax that mean they want stick on `POSIX` right?

Answer (score 1):

I found *one* bit of functionality that `[` implements but `[[` does not. However, it's not something you should be using anyway, so I wouldn't call it a reason to use `[` over `[[`.

The `-a` and `-o` operators for boolean AND and OR are supported by `test`:

```
if [ 3 -eq 3 -a 4 -eq 4 ]; then
    echo true
fi
```

However, trying to use them with `[[` is a syntax error:

```
# The correct version is
# if [[ 3 -eq 3 && 4 -eq 4 ]]; then echo yay; fi
$ if [[ 3 -eq 3 -a 4 -eq 4 ]]; then echo yay; fi
bash: syntax error in conditional expression
bash: syntax error near `-a'
```

But if you are using `[[`, you would use `&&` and `||` instead, even if `-a` and `-o` were supported. Further, even the POSIX standard recommends using `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` in place of `-a` (and `[ ... ] || [ ... ]` instead of `-o`); the two operators are extensions that aren't required of a conforming POSIX implementation.

---

Other reasons, aside from portability concerns, are simply going to be matters of opinion.

Comment: I wouldn't say that `[[` doesn't implement the functionality of `-a` and `-o`; I'd say that they're spelled `&&` and `||` there.

Comment: I agree with Charles Duffy. But, more generally, most of the advantages of `[[` can be spun as functionality deficits. For example, consider `foo='3 -lt 4' ; if [ $foo ] ; then ...`.

Comment: Fair enough, but it is true you cannot simply "wrap" 100% of valid `[ ... ]` commands in another layer of square brackets and have it work. (My original answer was going to be that there is *nothing* that `[` supports that `[[` does not, until I stumbled on this little tidbit, ruakh's valid point aside.)

Answer (score 1):

Other than the portability benefits of `[` and the newer features and safety/correctness properties of `[[` that have already been discussed there is one downside to using `[[` that is worth being aware of (to my mind).

Specifically, what happens when you use it to validate/etc. numeric values.

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29980940/258523) about it.

I also discussed it in the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31430511/258523).

Specifically, this

```
foo=bar
[ 5 -eq "$foo" ]
```

will output an error and `[` will return `2` whereas this (with or without quotes around the variable)

```
foo=bar
[[ 5 -eq "$foo" ]]
```

will silently return `1` and this

```
bar=5
foo=bar
[[ 5 -eq "$foo" ]]
```

will return `0`.

That is `[[` evaluates bare-variables recursively. It also, as indicated in ruakh's comment on chepner's answer will expand expressions in variables.

So

```
foo="10 / 2"
[[ 5 -eq "$foo" ]]
```

will also return true.

Now, this may be exactly what you want but means you have to work harder to validate input/etc. then you would with `[`.

Comment: Interesting. POSIX doesn't seem to specify this kind of recursive lookup, although it doesn't forbid it, either. In `dash`, `echo $(( foo ))` is an error, but `echo $(( $foo ))` works. A third level of indirection is right out; with  `baz=foo`, neither `echo $(( baz ))` nor `echo $(( $baz ))` works.

Comment: @chepner `echo $(( foo ))` when `$foo` contains a numeric value is POSIX specified to work (and does seem to in `dash` here, and `dash -c 'echo $(( foo ))'` returns `0` as expected. `dash -c 'echo $(( $foo ))'` on the other hand is an error the same as `dash -c 'echo $(( ))'` is) and yes, what happens when `$foo` *doesn't* contain a numerical value is unspecified which is what bash hangs its behavior on. Yeah, `dash` has the single-level expansion that makes more sense to me (though the error indicates it expanded the variable and *then* blew up as opposed to not expanding and blowing up).